# Why does Python allow mixed type lists?

Tags: python

Is there a reason that Python allows lists to contain multiple types? If I had a mixed collection of objects I would think the safe data type to use would be a tuple. Also, I find it strange that list methods (like sort) can be called on mixed lists  so I assume there must be a good reason for allowing this. It appears at first glance that this would make writing type safe functions much more difficult.

Comment: Because Python doesn't have type safety at all.

Comment: As much as I would encourage others to make their code type safe, being type safe isn't everything and it hasn't been a priority of Python to make things type safe.

Comment: In that case, why distinguish between tuples and lists at all?

Comment: Python is dynamically typed, and requiring a consistent element type for lists doesn't provide much benefit when there's no requirement of a consistent type for *variables*.

Comment: "why distinguish between tuples and lists" - mostly so one can be mutable and the other can be hashable.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between a tuple and a list is that lists are mutable and tuples are not.  So its not about data type safety, its about whether or not you want the elements to be able to be changed

Comment: Note that tuples are only “shallowly” immutable, and they can contain mutable types.  So `t = (1, 'x', []); t[2].append('y')` will change the value of a tuple.